# ASP.net textbox centered text

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have an asp.net form that is styled with CSS. I am trying to input a string into a textbox through the code behind the asp form.

**Problem**: All text that goes into any asp.net textbox is centered and in one line [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USFYX.png)

**Attempted** **solution**: Created a class in my CSS form and changed margins and alignments. Surrounded the textbox in a div with the class

**Question**: How do I revert the CSS back so all ASP.NET textbox's are back to normal

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: Apply those CSS changes to a CSS class then add and remove the class from the textbox as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add class attribute to the form element then the given styles apply for all the elements within that form element.

Instead of doing that if you want to apply style for only one element add id attribute to the element and give styles.

Ex:

```
 .form {
    text-align: center;
}
```

above code apply center text for all elements.

```
<input id="txtBxId " value="Hello World!"/>
    #txtBxId {
        text-align: center;
        color: red;
    }
```

but if you do like this it will apply for single element

Answer (score 0):

you can use textbox in centered text with 2 ways :
1) tag

```
<center>
    <asp:TextBox ID='text'> 
</center>
```

2) Input :

```
<html>
<style>
    #txtBxId {
        text-align: center;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<body>
<input id="txtBxId " value="Hello World!"/>
</body>
</html>
```